# How do I put VBA Query Tables data in one Column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image]

Help please, I am using code below.  I only need the data to go into column N, when using the for loop, it goes across all  columns. How can I fix this?

```
 Dim W As Worksheet: Set W = ActiveSheet
Last = W.Range("A1500").End(xlUp).Row
If Last = 7 Then Exit Sub
Dim Symbols As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

' Code below Loops on the stock tickers and concatenate them
For i = 8 To Last Step 200
    Symbols = "" 'value to reset the string during loop

    For j = i To i + 199
        Symbols = Symbols & W.Cells(j, 1) & "+"
    Next j

        Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols) - 1)

        'Debug.Print Symbols ' delete this later

  Dim URL As String: URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbols & "&f=snl1p2kjr5rp6s7m3m8"

         With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=W.Range("$N$" & i))
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .SaveData = True
        End With

Next i
```

Comment: `I only need the data to go into column N, when using the for loop, it goes across all the rows` ... what does that mean? If you want it all to go to N, do you mean you want it all in N1. If not, then it has to go to different rows in N

Comment: It goes across all the columns instead of only in Column N. Every iteration of the for loop puts the data in the adjacent column but in the correct row as shown in image.

Comment: I see your update, your question is now clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by the fact that adding a new `QueryTable` pushes the previously-added `QueryTable`(s) one column to the right.

That can be undone by adding the following code immediately after the `End With` statement. For each new `QueryTable` after the first one, this will delete the single column of cells just to the left of the previously-added `QueryTable`(s), thus re-aligning them horizontally.

```
If i <> 8 Then
    Range("N8", W.Range("$N$" & i).Offset(-1)).Delete (xlShiftToLeft)
End If
```

Comment: Glad to be of service. If my answer [resolved your issue](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers), please [accept it](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). Once you have sufficient reputation, you can [upvote](http://superuser.com/help/why-vote) helpful answers as well.